# how to use 'issubset' with multiple element in tuple (python)

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of tuples as this following.

```
a = [('a','b'),('a','c'),('a','d'),('b','d'),('b','e'),('e','f')];
```

and I want to check  `data = [('a','b','c')]` is a sub set of a or not

I did

```
set(data).issubset(set(a));
```

but I got result as a false which is not supposed to  I not sure what I did wrong here

Comment: `False` is correct.  The items in `a` are tuples, and the items in `data` is a single tuple.  The single tuple in `data` does not match any of the tuples in `a`, so the answer should be `False`.

Comment: So, what where you trying to achieve, which `issubset()` is not doing?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean: Are `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'` all present in at least one of the tuples in `a`? Such that the test should return true for `[('a','b'),('a','c')]` and false for `[('a','b'),('a','z')]`.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood using issubset() but my goal is to check those ('a','b','c') should be  derive in ('a','b') and ('a','c') which are the subset of a .. In contrary ('a','c','e') shouldn't be a subset of a since ('c','e') is not a part of set a

Comment: @someone So you actually want to test if any of the tuples in `a` are a subsequence/subset (note difference!) of any of the tuples in `data`?

Comment: @someone: if your new understanding changes your question then please edit (or delete) your question.  It's now unclear whether you know the answer or want to modify your question to more clearly state the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

`data :: [3-tuple]` where as `a :: [2-tuple]`. A `2-tuple` is different from `3-tuple` in that `set` operations don't apply. You can do:

```
g = (e for t in a for e in t)
set(*data).issubset(g)  # True
```